# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')

Tags: javascript

I am seeing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
> at (index):15
> at Array.forEach ()
> at IntersectionObserver. ((index):12)

Here is the code:

```
<script>window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            const id = entry.target.getAttribute('id');
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`).parentElement.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                document.querySelector(`nav li a[href="#${id}"]`).parentElement.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
    });

    
    document.querySelectorAll('div[id]').forEach((div) => {
        observer.observe(div);
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Script is working well, but seeing errors in the console. Kindly let me know what to do.

Comment: The selector isn't finding a matching element. You need to figure out why the expected element isn't there. Or check the result of `querySelector()` before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

QuerySelector is returning a NULL value, which does not have the property “parentElement”.

If not finding a matching element is expected behavior for your app, you’ll need to handle for that situation, or adjust your query.

Maybe those elements aren’t in the DOM when the queries are run.